# How to paginate a related model in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, model, pagination, eloquent

i have two model which is RoomCategory and Room. and i want to paginate all rooms related by each roomcategory by a foreach loop, here's my MVC.

Model

```
class RoomCategory extends \Eloquent {
    public function Room(){
        return $this->hasMany('Room','category_id','id','RoomCategory');
    }
}

class Room extends \Eloquent {
    public function RoomCategory(){
        return $this->belongsTo('RoomCategory','id','category_id','Room');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $room_category = RoomCategory::get()
        ->with('Room')->paginate(1);

    return View::make('pages.roomlist', compact('room_category'));
}
```

View

```
@foreach($room_category as $category)
    {{$category->name}}
    @foreach($category->room as $rooms)

         {{$rooms->name}}

         {{$category->room->links()}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

and i got this error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with()

can someone help me how to paginate those rooms under a foreach loop of the roomcategories. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you have to fetch all room categories, loop through them and then loop through the each room category rooms.

This is example code:

```
public function index()
{
    $room_category = RoomCategory::with('Room')->paginate(1);

    return View::make('pages.roomlist', compact('room_category'));
}
```

Your view:

```
@foreach($room_category as $category)
    {{$category->name}}
    @foreach($category->Room as $rooms)
        {{$rooms->name}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need get() method if you are using paginate. Replace this

```
$room_category = RoomCategory::get()
    ->with('Room')->paginate(1);
```

with this

```
$room_category = RoomCategory::with('Room')->paginate(1);
```

**EDIT**

It would be good if you don't use pagination links for room in your index page, just paginate your roomcategory.

```
$room_category = RoomCategory::with([
                'Room' => function($query) {
                    $query->latest()->limit(5);
                }
                ])->paginate(3);
```

On your index view paginate the categories and make a link to each category page and paginate your room their

index.blade.php

```
@foreach($room_category as $room_cat)
    @foreach($room_cat->Room as $room)
        <div class="room-section"></div>
    @endforeach
    <a href="{{ url('category', $room_cat->id) }}">View more of this category</a>
@endforeach

{{ $room_category->links() }}
```

Your Controller

```
public function showCategory($id)
{
    $room_category = RoomCategory::with([
                'Room' => function($query) {
                    $query->latest()->paginate(8);
                }
                ])->find($id);

    return View::make('category.show', compact('$room_category'));
}
```

and category/show.blade.php you can paginate room

```
@foreach($room_category->Room as $room)
    <div class="room-section"></div>
@endforeach

{{ $room_category->Room()->links() }}
```

Comment: had an error again when i do this code
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links()`

Comment: it paginates the $room_category not the  $category->room